# Piano both hands, learning curve

Tags: piano, learning, self-learning, digital-piano, hand-independence

I had started learning a piece of music with both hands on piano. I have noticed that at the beginning, playing with both hands seems impossible. That is, one hand stops playing, presses wrong keys, or paces slower or faster. But, after a while, it gets simpler and simpler as if you do not need to pay attention to each hand separately.

I am wondering if this is going to be true for every pieces on piano?

Answer (score 4):

It's just like riding a bike. At first, it seems very difficult but once you get the hang of it you don't even need to think about it.

It's the same way for learning to play the piano hands together. As pieces get more difficult, it can be tricky to get your hands to work together properly, but you won't ever have to relearn playing hands together again.

Answer (score 2):

You can also think of it like basketball.  It's comfortable if you only dribble and shoot with one hand, but it's better if you practice both and alternate seamlessly.  You will reach a point where you won't think as much as you are now.

You will notice that there are certain techniques and patterns for each of the hands.  The more you expose your hands to them, the more fluent you will be.

Be patient, because it just takes time.